# Alternating Series

Tags: calculus

A professor of mine gave me this problem and asked me to figure it out. I can not seem to figure it out.

> Express ln($2/3$) as an alternating series and use alternating series estimates to find lower and upper bounds for ln($2/3$) less than $10^{-2}$ apart.

The only thing that comes to mind is that I express ln($2/3$) = $-$ln($1-(-1/2))$.

How would I continue to pursue this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is right. Note that
$$\ln(2/3) = - \ln(3/2) = -\ln(1+1/2)$$
Now recall that
$$\ln(1+x) = x - \dfrac{x^2}2 + \dfrac{x^3}3 - \dfrac{x^4}4 + \dfrac{x^5}5 \mp$$
To get a bound on the error due to truncation, if you truncate at $\dfrac{x^4}4$ for instance, your error is guaranteed to be less than $\dfrac{x^5}5$. So in general, if you truncate at the term $-\dfrac{x^{2n}}{2n}$, your error is guaranteed to be less than $\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. Use this fact to get to the desired precision you want.